# Making Batches of 50 from an Object in Java

Tags: java, pagination

I am stuck with an issue in my app. I want to implement a pagination kind of functionality in my application but due to the existing behaviour I cannot move forward with the standard ways of achieving pagination in my application.

Problem: I have a bean object with all the data in it. I want to device a logic for breaking down the object into groups of 50. So consider, if I have 5000 configs in my object, I will first break it down into first 50 and same will be displayed on UI. Further, I will have to continue the process by breaking the reamining 450 configs in the batches of 50. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed with this logic??

My approach: In my existing code, I am checking for the size of the object. If the size data. If its more than 50. I am setting a flag as true. This flag will be used in JSP/JS, to retrigger a DOJO call for fetching data again. Please find the snippet of the code.

```
public ActionForward sdconfigLoadServiceGroups(ActionMapping actionMapping,
        ActionForm actionForm, HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {

    String groupUniqueId = servletRequest.getParameter("groupUniqueId");
    Boolean retriggerRequestFlag = false;

    // Get the ui group
    HashMap sdConfigDetailsHashMap = (HashMap) ((DynaActionForm) actionForm).get(SD_CONFIG_DETAILS);
    TreeMap sdConfigTreeMap = (TreeMap) sdConfigDetailsHashMap.get("SDConfigTree");
    Boolean viewOnly=(Boolean) sdConfigDetailsHashMap.get("ViewOnly");
    Order order = orderManager.getOrder((Long) sdConfigDetailsHashMap.get("OrderId"));

    SDConfigUITab sdConfigUITab = sdConfig2Manager.getTabByGroupUniqueId(groupUniqueId, sdConfigTreeMap);
    SDConfigUIGroup sdConfigUIGroup = sdConfig2Manager.getGroupByGroupUniqueId(servletRequest.getParameter("groupUniqueId"), sdConfigUITab);
    //TODO: Adding logger to check the total number of sections
    logger.info("All Sections==="+sdConfigUIGroup.getSections());
    logger.info("Total Sections?? "+sdConfigUIGroup.getSections().size());
    long size = Long.valueOf(sdConfigUIGroup.getSections().size());
    if (size != 0 && size > 50) {
        sdConfigUIGroup  = loadDynamicConfigs(sdConfigUIGroup);
        retriggerRequestFlag = true;
    }

    servletRequest.setAttribute("retriggerRequest", retriggerRequestFlag); 
    servletRequest.setAttribute("groupUniqueId", servletRequest.getParameter("groupUniqueId"));
    servletRequest.setAttribute("sdConfigUIGroup", sdConfigUIGroup);
    servletRequest.setAttribute("sdConfigUITab", sdConfigUITab);
    servletRequest.setAttribute("sdConfigUITabId", sdConfigUITab.getTabId());
    servletRequest.setAttribute("currentOrderId", order.getOrderId());
    servletRequest.setAttribute("viewOnly", viewOnly);


    return actionMapping.findForward("sdconfigLoadServiceGroups");
}

 public SDConfigUIGroup loadDynamicConfigs(SDConfigUIGroup sdConfigUIGroup) {

     //logic for breaking into batches of 50 goes here

 }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome :) Thanks !!!

Comment: What is wrong with your posted code? Currently you've described your requirements, but not what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Duncan.. I am unable to figure out the logic for breaking the contents in the batches of 50. need some hints here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a track,

- set startIndex and fetchCount in your session (depending on the life cycle)
- In your loadDynamicConfigs, iterate through loadDynamicConfigs and pull 50 sections each time.
- Next time when user clicks on "Next" (if available) they use the latest startIndex and fetchSize to pull the next batch
- Note that your "Next" link/button on the page should call another mapping method to do pagination.